# SQL nested and/or statement

Tags: sql

I'm stuck on an SQL statement. I am trying to get the following:

```
Select fields from the rentedHouseTbl WHERE
```

a property matches a propertyIDTr

```
**AND**

    the rentedHouseMoveInDateTr is less than or equal to today's date AND
    the rentedHouseMoveOutDateTr is NULL 

    OR

    the rentedHouseMoveInDateTr is less than or equal to today's date AND 
    the rentedHouseMoveOutDateTr is greater than today's date.

If this returns results then the property is occupied
else it is vacant
```

The SQL statement I am using is:

```
SELECT * FROM rentedHouseTbl where propertyIDTr = '1' AND ( (rentedHouseMoveInDateTr <= CURDATE() AND rentedHouseMoveOutDateTr IS NULL) OR (rentedHouseMoveInDateTr <= CURDATE() AND rentedHouseMoveOutDateTr > CURDATE()) )
```

But I am not getting the expected results. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM rentedHouseTbl 
where 
where propertyIDTr = '1'and
rentedHouseMoveInDateTr <= CURDATE() AND (rentedHouseMoveOutDateTr IS NULL or rentedHouseMoveOutDateTr > CURDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks! That's brilliant. It's shorter and actually makes much more sense! I think I made it worse by testing the results in my php program instead of in mysql and my code was not saving the NULL! I will be using this!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT * FROM rentedHouseTbl 
  WHERE propertyIDTr = '1' 
     AND rentedHouseMoveInDateTr <= CURDATE() 
     AND ISNULL(rentedHouseMoveOutDateTr, DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) <> CURDATE()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM rentedHouseTbl 
where (rentedHouseMoveInDateTr <= CURDATE() AND rentedHouseMoveOutDateTr IS NULL) 
OR (rentedHouseMoveInDateTr <= CURDATE() AND rentedHouseMoveOutDateTr > CURDATE())
```